# is there a Error look up function FOR MBEDTLS?

Tags: c, mbedtls

I am currently using mbedtls for a project. I want to know if there is a error look up function at all that will take a error code and give me back a error message of some kind?

Comment: [mbedtls_strerror](https://tls.mbed.org/api/error_8h.html#a8c41c149b77a4807115b19c2af858558)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can look at the reference application: 
[strerror](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/util/strerror.c) to see what API you need to call to read the error as string.